# File location error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to implement skipthoughts vectors in my VQA project but I am facing a problem in reading a file from a specified location. This is a piece of skipthoughts code

```
path_to_models = 'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/skip_thought'
path_to_tables = 'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/skip_thought'

path_to_umodel = path_to_models + 'uni_skip.npz'
path_to_bmodel = path_to_models + 'bi_skip.npz'

def load_model():
    """
    Load the model with saved tables
    """
    # Load model options
    print ('Loading model parameters...')
    with open('%s.pkl'%path_to_umodel, 'rb') as f:
        uoptions = pkl.load(f)
    with open('%s.pkl'%path_to_bmodel, 'rb') as f:
        boptions = pkl.load(f)
```

This is the error message when I call skipthoughts.py

```
File "C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention 
Networks/skip_thought/new_skip_thought.py", line 11, in <module>
model = skipthoughts.load_model()

File "skipthoughts.py", line 37, in load_model
with open('%s.pkl'%path_to_umodel, 'rb') as f:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/skip_thoughtuni_skip.npz.pkl'
```

The file location is not correct

> 'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/**skip_thoughtuni_skip.npz.pkl**'

It should be

> 'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/**skip_thought/uni_skip.npz.pkl**'

Comment: The you have to ad the slash to your path strings or use `os.path.join()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem in your program is the wrong file path that is saved in `path_to_umodel` and `path_to_bmodel`.
To solve the problem, you can modify the variables `path_to_models` and `path_to_tables` by adding a `/` at the end of them as:

```
path_to_models = 'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/skip_thought/'
```

and

```
path_to_tables = 'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/skip_thought/'
```

or you can add the `/` in beginning of `uni_skip.npz` and `bi_skip.npz` and then, those lines become:

```
path_to_umodel = path_to_models + '/uni_skip.npz'
path_to_bmodel = path_to_models + '/bi_skip.npz'
```

Even better, you can use the os.path.join function built into python's `os` module.
Just `import os` in the beginning of the program and use it as:

```
path_to_umodel = os.path.join(path_to_models, os.sep, 'uni_skip.npz')
path_to_bmodel = os.path.join(path_to_models, os.sep, 'bi_skip.npz')
```

Here, `os.sep` is the file separator used on the platform on which the code is running.
For windows, it is `\` and for linux and unix, it `/`.
It is better to use `os.sep` instead of hardcoding some value in its place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `os.path.join`, like this:

```
import os

path_to_models = 'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/skip_thought'
path_to_tables = 'C:/Users/Downloads/Stacked Attention Networks/skip_thought'

path_to_umodel = os.path.join(path_to_models, 'uni_skip.npz')
path_to_bmodel = os.path.join(path_to_models, 'bi_skip.npz')
```